# How do I only display the value from JSON String

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/application").then((response) => {
            setListofApplications(response.data)
        });
    }, []);


         <main id="body-content">
            <div>
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Display Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Response</th>
                            <th scope="col">Submitted Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Approval</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {listofApplications.map((value) => {
                        let data = 
                         JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value.application_data));
                        return <tr>
                            <td>{value.id}</td>
                            <td>{value.display_name}</td>
                            <td>{value.application_type}</td>
                            <td>{data.first_name}</td>
                            <td>{value.createdAt}</td>
                            <td>{value.approval}</td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        </main>



const initalValues= {
        display_name: "",
        applicaiton_data: [{
            "first_name": '',
            "middle_i": '',
            "last_name": '',
            "rp_name": '',
            "age": '',
            "email": '',
            "history": '',
            "expirence": '',
            "why": '',
            "bring": '',
            "vac_ban": '',
        }],
        application_type: "",
        approval: "false",
    };
1 Test ca ["first_name":"test","middle_i":"test","last_name":"test","rp_name":"test","age":"test","email":"test","history":"test","experience":"test","why":"test","bring":"test","vac_ban":"test"] false 2021-04-17


(Response)
0:
application_data: "[
\"first_name\":\"test\",
\"middle_i\":\"test\",
\"last_name\":\"test\",
\"rp_name\":\"test\",
\"age\":\"test\",
\"email\":\"test\",
\"history\":\"test\",
\"experience\":\"test\",
\"why\":\"test\",
\"bring\":\"test\",
\"vac_ban\":\"test\
"]"
application_type: "ca"
approval: "false"
createdAt: "2021-04-17"
display_name: "Jerome_M"
id: 1
updatedAt: "2021-04-17"
```

This is what I get back on page ( wasn't worried about design, just want to know how to call it correctly. These values won't be changing once submitted just read. Which is why I choose the json route.

how would I only show the strings not the ""?

Added how I am showing the data on the page using a table. If I have to change it, I don't mind. Just want to learn how to do this correctly.

Comment: can you provide codesandbox liink for this output

Comment: What are you trying to read? The array at the bottom? Where are you attempting to read it?

Comment: I cannot, the code has two sections client & server. But the output of the code is 1 Test ca ["first_name":"test","middle_i":"test","last_name":"test","rp_name":"test","age":"test","email":"test","history":"test","experience":"test","why":"test","bring":"test","vac_ban":"test"] false 2021-04-17

Comment: I am already reading it, it's being called from the database by using axios.get I am just printing out the response by {value.id} {value.display_name} {value.application_type} {value.application_data} {value.approval} {value.createdAt}

Comment: 1 is {value.id} test is {value.dispay_name} ca is {value.application_type} the array is {value.application_data} false is {value.approval} data is {value.createdAt}

Comment: Ah, so are you asking how to render `value.application_data` then?

Comment: Yes, without all the quotation marks

Comment: Can you share your *actual* `response.data` value? Or minimally a single entry/element?

Comment: response.data is getting turned into value.cloumn name in db.

Comment: @DrewReese Added it to the bottom of the question

Comment: Think you could create a simple running codesandbox with that state and attempt at rendering?

Comment: @DrewReese not able to, but this is what the response is https://gyazo.com/ea6bc7460f9e23cf83bd24cec782e1e9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display JSON without the "" (into object) you could use JSON.parse()

```js
var json = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.name + ", " + obj.age)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've said I am calling the data from a database.

Comment: It doesn't change anything where it come from. If you have a JSON that you want to be an object use JSON.parse.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question to reflect what I think you meant.

Comment: If I just do the JSON.parse(value.applicaiton_data) it throws a cross origin error

Comment: This is something else. If you have an other question feel free to do another post.